# How to change deeply nested states without explicitly providing a lot of context in actions?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have items nested a couple of levels deep:

```
const initialState = {
  sections: [
    {
      name: 'Section 1',
      categories: [
        {
          name: 'Category 1',
          checklist: [
            { name: 'Item 1', checked: false },
            { name: 'Item 2', checked: true },
            { name: 'Item 3', checked: false },
          ]
        },
        // more categories
      ],
    },
    // more sections
  ],
};
```

I was wondering if there's a way to change their state (say, toggle the `checked` property) without explicitly passing a lot of context:

```
function toggleCheckbox(sectionId, categoryId, itemId) {
  return {
    type: 'TOGGLE_CHECKBOX',
    sectionId: sectionId,
    categoryId: categoryId,
    itemId: itemId,
  };
}

function reducer(state = initialState, action) {    
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'TOGGLE_CHECKBOX':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        sections: state.sections.map(function (section, i) {
          return i === action.sectionId ? Object.assign({}, section, {
            categories: section.categories.map(function (category, j) {
              return j === action.categoryId ? Object.assign({}, category, {
                checklist: category.checklist.map(function (item, k) {
                  return k === action.itemId ? Object.assign({}, item, {
                    checked: !item.checked,
                  }) : item;
                }),
              }) : category;
            }),
          }) : section;
        }),
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

As logic for sections, categories and checklists grows, I might want to extract them as separate reducers, but because they are nested I don't see a way to do this.

Here's a [bin](http://jsbin.com/tibohe/edit?js,console,output) with this store visualized with React.

I guess my question has two parts:

1. How can I extract them as separate reducers?
2. How can I avoid providing so much context explicitly and avoid all that mapping which really only changes a nested item's state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested objects can definitely be painful.  Dan has a little blurb on nested entities in the [Redux docs](http://rackt.org/redux/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html#note-on-nested-entities).

> If you have nested entities, or if you let users edit received
>   entities, you should keep them separately in the state as if it was a
>   database. In pagination information, you would only refer to them by
>   their IDs. This lets you always keep them up to date.

I've made a **[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zowejeyuki/1/edit?js,output)** modifying your example to demonstrate, but the gist of it consists of flattening out your state tree a little bit.

```
const initialState = {
  sections: [
    {
      name: 'Section 1',
      categories: [ 'Category 1'],
    },
    // more sections
  ],
  categories: [
    {
      name: 'Category 1',
      checklist: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3']
    },
  ],
  items: [
    {
      name: 'Item 1',
      checked: false
    },
    {
      name: 'Item 2',
      checked: true
    },
    {
      name: 'Item 3',
      checked: false
    },
  ]
```

};

The item reducer just needs an `name` now to know which one to update, and sections/categories keep track of which items they own.  Now you can split off dedicated category, section, and item reducers that can each deal with their own area of concern!

*If you want items with the same name in different categories, you'll have to introduce a new ID to keep them separate from eachother... but using name was simplest for now*

Comment: This is a very good answer. Just one question, in my case I have multiple sections which all have the same categories, but each of these categories have different checklists. Do I then treat these repeating categories like they're not the same and give them all different IDs? So if I have 3 sections, each of them has 3 categories, I have 9 categories in total in the `categories` field?

Comment: Hmm.  I think it kinda depends on your usage, but most likely you'll want 9 categories in total, since each one needs a different checklists.  If you tried to share the 3 categories across all the sections,  you're categories would need separate `items` lists for each section. 

Probably a lot more straight forward to give each section it's own unique categories, even if they're named the same.